# What is the usage of pointers types over object type inside a structure?

Tags: c++, pointers, go, sdk, structure

I am having a rest service running.
API call will populate below structure which user has passed with the REST call.

```
type struct Body{
    param1 *string
    param2 string
}
```

Now I can process this request in my handler function. As a part of error handling in my handler function I'll do following,

> For param1(which is a pointer) I need to check if pointer is not nil and length of the string should not be 0.
>
> For param2 I just need to check if length of string should not be 0

Using string object will lead me to use fewer checks and write clean code. Then why most of the people use pointers in such case.

Comment: If `param1` is `nullptr` then that can signal there was an error processing it, but with an object you couldn't know. Sure if it was a string or int it could be `""` or `-1` respectively, but some generic object like `param1` you couldn't know, so it can help signal if there were issues processing it.

Comment: "Then why most of the people use pointers in such case." Most people do _not_ use `*string` in _this_ case. A `*string` lets you differentiate between "any string value including the empty string" and "no string value at all.

Comment: @SJ26 is your service written in Go or C++?

Comment: using golang @mkopriva

Comment: @SJ26 in the case you specified, where `param1` needs to have length greater than `0` to pass validation, you don't have to use a pointer. However there are other cases where the use of pointers makes sense. For example during updates where unmarshaling into an intermediate type (instead of directly into the target type) a `nil` pointer field may be used to indicate that no value was provided for that field and therefore no update of the corresponding field in the target type is necessary.

Comment: Another use case for pointers could be data for which a zero-value, or even a nil-value, is a valid option. So whether or not you should use a pointer field depends entirely on the use-cases for that field. @SJ26

Answer (score 2):

In go language, variables declared without an initial value are set to their zero values not `null` value.

- 0 for all integer types
- ""(empty string) for strings
- nil for interfaces, slices, pointers

So, when you need to differentiate between `null` value and zero value, you need to use `pointers` because `pointers` zero value is `nil`. Golang does not allow `null`, its version is nil, where some languages do.

**Example case:**

In database like MySql ""(empty string) and `0` is not null value for string and int types. If you need to save a string value for ""(empty string) and null value differently in the database you need to use pointer for the string in request body struct.